# Detecting system alert button tapped in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI I want to detect if user pressed "Allow" button in Push Notification system alert. How can I detect which button is pressed in alert?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to know specifically which *button* was tapped? Can’t you instead just see if the permission itself was granted afterward?

Comment: What kind of system alert are you talking about? Specifically what?

Comment: I meant Push Notification alert to get user permission.

Comment: I want to update UI according to user's decision that is why I want to know which button was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getNotificationSettings` from `UNUserNotificationCenter` to get the current settings.

Repeatedly call this on a timer after you show the system alert to know if the user accepted or declined.

Apple Documentation:
[UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter)
[getNotificationSettings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649524-getnotificationsettings)

Answer (score 0):

This code block helped me to detect which button is pressed

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { granted, _ in 
}
```